# Deserialize JSON Data - Custom Deserialization Using Jackson JSON Parser

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I am trying to deserialize the following incoming JSON data:

```
{"TimeTable":[{"PersonID":"100649771",
..,..,..,"xx":null},
{"PersonID":"100631701",
..,..,..,"xx":{"abc":1234,"xyz":5678}}],
"xxx":"","xxxx":0,"xxxxx":false}
```

But I am facing a problem while parsing using a custom deserialization block made up of:

```
    jParser.nextToken();
while ((jParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY)) {
    String innerField = jParser.getCurrentName();
jParser.nextToken();
```

But in this way I am skipping the array contents While parsing for the second row in the array (as illustrated in the JSON sample above^).

***UPDATE*:** Here is the [method](http://pastebin.com/JbJ2SEMZ)(PasteBin Link) which is trying to parse the JSON data coming in the described format. Is there a way I can bind the JSON data directly to my bean? (IMO it appeared way more complex to me as because of the JSON structure; Moreover I can't change the JSON structure nor the bean structure. So, I just dropped the idea of binding directly :| ) Anyways [here](http://pastebin.com/dnrMqGeQ)(PasteBin Link) is the bean as well.

Following is the sample of the incoming JSON Data:

```
{"Schedules":[{"PersonID":"100649771",
"HasSchedule":false,
"TripType":null,
"StickerNumber":null,
"VehicleRegNo":null,
"ExpectedStartDate":null,
"ActualStartDate":null,
"ActualEndDate":null,
"PersonScheduledDate":null,
"Shift":null,
"ColdCall":null,
"PickupLocationCoord":null},
{"PersonID":"100631701",
"HasSchedule":true,
"TripType":"P",
"StickerNumber":"PC0409",
"VehicleRegNo":"ASJHAHSP1758",
"ExpectedStartDate":"16 Aug 2013, 10:00:00",
"ActualStartDate":"16 Aug 2013, 10:02:52",
"ActualEndDate":"16 Aug 2013, 14:14:12",
"PersonScheduledDate":null,
"Shift":"02:30 PM",
"ColdCall":"N",
"PickupLocationCoord":{"Latitude":92.01011101,"Longitude":48.01011101}}],
"ErrorMessage":"","ErrorCode":0,"HasError":false}
```

Please can anyone fireup some pointers for me here in order- to deserialize 'em correctly?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED

Among other things, you are mixing up the two aproaches to read a JSON stream: using `readTree()` to get all your JSON data in a memory tree (like XML's DOM) but also using a `JsonParser` to read a JSON stream token by token (like XML's JAX). The following is a method that does almost the same using `readTree()`, which seems to be more appropriate to you as you are reading JSON already loaded in a `String`:

```
public List<VehicleInformationBean> getAllVehiclesInTree(String response) {

    List<VehicleInformationBean> vehicleList = new ArrayList<VehicleInformationBean>();

    try {
        PersonInformationBean mPersonInformationBean;
        DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(sContext);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(response);

        if ((root.get(ServiceConstant.ErrorCode).asInt()) != 0 || !root.has(ServiceConstant.Schedules)) {
            return vehicleList;
        }

        for(JsonNode element: root.get(ServiceConstant.Schedules)) {
            VehicleInformationBean lstVehicleInformation = new VehicleInformationBean();
            if (element.has(ServiceConstant.PersonID)) {
                String personId = element.get(ServiceConstant.PersonID).asText();
                mPersonInformationBean = mDatabaseHelper.getPersonDetailById(personId);
                lstVehicleInformation.setPersonID(personId);
                lstVehicleInformation.setName(mPersonInformationBean.getName());
                lstVehicleInformation.setPickupLocation(mPersonInformationBean.getPickupLocation());
                lstVehicleInformation.setDropLocation(mPersonInformationBean.getDropLocation());
            }
            lstVehicleInformation.setTripType(element.get(ServiceConstant.TripType).textValue());
            lstVehicleInformation.setStickerNumber(element.get(ServiceConstant.StickerNumber).textValue());
            lstVehicleInformation.setVehicleRegNo(element.get(ServiceConstant.VehicleRegNo).textValue());
            lstVehicleInformation.setExpectedStartDate(element.get(ServiceConstant.ExpectedStartDate).textValue());
            lstVehicleInformation.setActualStartDate(element.get(ServiceConstant.ActualStartDate).textValue());
            lstVehicleInformation.setActualEndDate(element.get(ServiceConstant.ActualEndDate).textValue());
            lstVehicleInformation.setPersonScheduledDate(element.get(ServiceConstant.PersonScheduledDate).textValue());
            lstVehicleInformation.setShift(element.get(ServiceConstant.Shift).textValue());
            if (element.has("PickupLocationCoord")) {
                JsonNode coords = element.get("PickupLocationCoord");
                if(coords.has(ServiceConstant.Latitude)) {
                    lstVehicleInformation.setLatitude(coords.get(ServiceConstant.Latitude).asDouble());
                }
                if(coords.has(ServiceConstant.Longitude)) {
                    lstVehicleInformation.setLongitude(coords.get(ServiceConstant.Longitude).asDouble());
                }
            } else if (element.has(ServiceConstant.ColdCall)) {
                lstVehicleInformation.setColdCall(element.get(ServiceConstant.ColdCall).textValue());
            }
        vehicleList.add(lstVehicleInformation);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO doing something with exception or throw it if it can't be handled here
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return vehicleList;
}
```

There are some validations and extra code you need to add to this method for it to do **exactly** what your original method does. This method only shows you the main idea of how to do it.

Comment: hey, thanks for replying here. Can you please tell me what difference will it make if I declare and init. a `token` as given above^. While I understand commenting out  `//jParser.nextToken();` will certainly skip fetching a tag (a null; when going over to the second element-tree of the array) :| Also, I tried adjusting the `nextToken()` calls but my brian is all boggled down as I have some huge nested while loops lying around :(

Comment: With the `token` variable you catch the reference to the token object once and you don't have to recover it again if you need it for other operations

Comment: Nope..din't worked. Actually now I am getting the reference to an object twice in the while loop as the value of `token` isn't changing in the first iteration so I keep getting the same JSON object twice. And in the third iteration I get the next object.

Comment: srry for the delay; crazy weekend :D. Here is the [method](http://pastebin.com/JbJ2SEMZ)(PasteBin Link) which is trying to parse the JSON data coming in the described format. Is there a way I can bind the JSON data directly to my bean? (IMO it appeared way more complex to me so I just dropped the idea :| ) Anyways [here](http://pastebin.com/dnrMqGeQ)(PasteBin Link) is the bean as well.

Comment: @morgano I nearly made it using my code but yours is neat. Thanks :D